# To fetch the unique characters from a string?

Tags: c#, string

I want to extract unique characters from a string. For example:- `'AAABBBBBCCCCFFFFGGGGGDDDDJJJJJJ'` will return `'ABCFGDJ'`

I have tried below piece of code but now I want to optimize it.
Please suggest if anyone knows.

```
static string extract(string original)
 {
        List<char> characters = new List<char>();   
        string unique = string.Empty; 
        foreach (char letter in original.ToCharArray())    
         {  
             if (!characters.Contains(letter))   
             {      
                  characters.Add(letter);   
              }            
          }  
        foreach (char letter in characters)
        {  
              unique += letter;    
         }     
     return unique;
 }
```

Comment: "I want to optimize it" - why? Is this a performance bottleneck that you have found while profiling?

Comment: Not exactly the performnce bottleneck but ya I was looking for some more optimal solution if I can get.

Comment: @Oded Rahul is right.  Using repeated string concatenations in a loop is well known to have poor performance.  This is one of the most important use cases for `StringBuilder`.  Also, using the `Contains` method on a `List<T>` is relatively inefficient; this is one of the most important use cases for a `HashSet<T>`.  The code would be much more efficient using `HashSet<T>` instead of `List<T>` and changin `unique` into a `StringBuilder`.  But the linq solution is better: it runs efficiently *and* it is quicker and easier to code.

Comment: @phoog - My point was more one of "premature optimization". Why try to optimize something that works well and is not a known performance bottleneck for the _specific_ application (even if it is known to generally have non-optimal performance)?

Comment: @Oded and that point is well taken.  Still, it's instructive to consider optimization as a learning exercise, and it's good to get in the habit of using HashSet and StringBuilder in situations presented in this method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know if this is faster, but surely shorter

```
string s = "AAABBBBBCCCCFFFFGGGGGDDDDJJJJJJ";
var newstr = String.Join("", s.Distinct());
```

Comment: This would be using a HashSet internally so O(n), which is way faster than OPs O(n^2) approach

Comment: Will this not transform "AAABBBAAAA" into "AB"? The question does not define if that is the desired behaviour. Intuitively it seems "ABA" would be the right answer.

Comment: @DominiqueJacquel above code does the same as `extract` in OP's question

Comment: Just need to confirm one thing that will the output be in a sorted manner. I mean will it be sorted in ASCII format???

Comment: @RahulTripathi: No, it will be in the same order as the original input - just like in your code. If you wanted it to be sorted, you should have said so in the question.

Comment: @RahulTripathi you can use `String.Join("", s.Distinct().OrderBy(c=>c))` for sorting.

Comment: @L.B ... you are right. I guess a better example string would have eliminated any doubts regarding the "AAABBAAA" case.

Comment: @DominiqueJacquel If the requirement is more like yours (i.e. AABBAA becomes ABA), then there's a handy extension on MSDN for grouping by contiguous values. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138361.aspx

Comment: @Jon:- I was just confirming as I thought that Distinct() function performs it internally? :-(

Comment: @spender, I don't actually have such a requirement ... just trolling the site :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi: Nope - it's not actually guaranteed what the order will be, but the current (and most obvious) implementation is to yield the elements in the original order. See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-14-distinct.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Another LINQ approach, but not using `string.Join`:

```
var result = new string(original.Distinct().ToArray());
```

I honestly don't know which approach to string creation would be faster. It probably depends on whether `string.Join` ends up internally converting each element to a string before appending to a `StringBuilder`, or whether it has custom support for some well-known types to avoid that.

Comment: Man, LINQ is cool.  It's like a whole new way to work with data.

Comment: @user1477388... yes. Come and join the party!

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
var result = string.Join("", "AAABBBBBCCCCFFFFGGGGGDDDDJJJJJJ".Distinct());
```

Make sure that you include `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string str = "AAABBBBBCCCCFFFFGGGGGDDDDJJJJJJ"; 
string answer = new String(str.Distinct().ToArray());
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

if "AAABBBAAA" should return "ABA", then the following does it. Albeit not very fast.

```
List<char> no_repeats = new List<char>();
no_repeats.Add(s[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    if (s[i] != no_repeats.Last()) no_repeats.Add(s[i]);
}
string result = string.Join("", no_repeats);
```

Comment: Dominique:- I want my output to be just 'AB' as these two are the only disinct or unique characters here!!!!

Comment: in that case you have your solution above from @L.B